# Adding JOIN to array for Comma Separator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, join

I have a text field classified as an array

In my show view, I have:

```
<%= @location.supported_ad_types.join(' , ') %>
```

and that works fine

But when trying to add the JOIN inside the index.rb, I get this error:

```
undefined method `join' for "PNG , BMP , GIF":String
```

I know I am missing something very simple here.....

**Failing Code (Invoked in Index View)**

```
<% @locations.each do |location| %>
......
<%= location.supported_ad_types.join(' , ') %>
.......
<% end %>
```

Currently the attribute "supported_ad_types" is serialized as it can accept multiple values

**Model**

```
serialize :supported_ad_types, Array
```

**DB File Type**

```
 t.text :supported_ad_types, array: true
```

I am trying to achieve distinct formatting for display with a comma seperator: PNG, TIFF, BMP. I am getting this ["PNG", "TIFF", "BMP"].

Values are being chosen by the user from the location form:

```
 <%= f.select :supported_ad_types, supported_types_of_media, {include_blank: false, include_hidden: false}, {class: 'filter_select', style:'width:100%;', placeholder: 'Supported File Types', required: true, multiple: true} %>
```

Comment: please show where the `location` from the failing line is defined

Comment: Added. Failing inside INDEX view of Locations. '.join' works fine if invoked in the location 'show' but not on index

Comment: did you figure this out, I have the same problem it just ignores my joint when its inside the array